# AngularJS - REST Call Not Working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest

I know this question is a bit redundant and there are a ton of resources out there, but I have been at this for over a day now and I just cant see what I am doing wrong.

Edit*
I was wondering if I was having a problem with the CORS feature, so I hosted a subdomain and added support for this test subdomain...Still no data showing up...

http://test.spcomputerclub.com/news/

http://api.spcomputerclub.com/Help/Api/GET-Api-Forums

app.js

```
 var myApp = angular.module('myApp', [
'myControllers',
'myServices'
]);
```

controller.js

```
var myControllers = angular.module('myControllers', []);

myControllers.controller('myControllers', ['$scope', 'ForumIndexItem', function ($scope,    ForumIndexItem) {
$scope.data = {};

ForumIndexItem.query(function(response){
$scope.data.issues = response;
});

 }]);
```

service.js

```
var myServices = angular.module('myServices', ['ngResource']);

myServices.factory('ForumIndexItem', function ($resource) {
return $resource('http://api.XXXXXXXX.com/Api/Forums', {})
})
```

html

```
 <!doctype html>
 <html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Practice</title>
 <script src="lib/angular/angular.js"></script>
 <script src="lib/angular/angular-resource.js"></script>
 <script src="js/app.js"></script>
 <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
 <script src="js/services.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="ForumIndexItem in data.issues">
      <p>{{ForumIndexItem.ForumName}}</p>
    </li>
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You haven't actually asked a question. :)  What's not working about it?

Comment: Well my problem is that I am getting no data back from the call.